# Call endpoint that does not renew authentication cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5

We use cookie authentication with sliding expiration in a .NET 5-project. We want to call an endpoint to verify if the user is logged in or not, but that endpoint should not renew the auth cookie if the user is logged in.

So the question is: Is it possible to call an API endpoint that does not renew the auth-cookie?

**EDIT:**
Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication()
             .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, config =>
             {
                 config.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                 config.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/NoAccess";
                 config.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(settings.CookieSlidingExpirationInSeconds);
                 config.SlidingExpiration = true;
             });
```

Endpoint:

```
[Authorize]
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
public class LoginController : BaseApiController
{        
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult IsAuthenticated()
    {
        return Ok(
            new
            {
                IsAuthenticated = User?.Identity != null && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code for the method at present?

Comment: @Llama Updated with some code.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if there's a way in ASP.NET Core 5 but in ASP.Net Core 6 there's a new event on `CookieAuthenticationEvents` called `OnCheckSlidingExpiration` that could be used to prevent renewing the authentication cookie.

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/0ca2ed9af69e7e334b8e3c1de1d015017f138988/src/Security/Authentication/Cookies/src/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs#L98-L103

Comment: Seems to be what I'm looking for. To bad it's a few months away. :(

Comment: Adding this did not solve the issue of the login endpoint renewing the cookie on the request even with allowanonymous

Answer (score 1):

I know the question specifically says .NET 5, but if someone's in a similar situation to the one I was, they might find this helpful. Expanding upon @Kahbazi's answer in .NET 6 you can override the default cookie authentication event methods, one of those is the one @Kahbazi mentioned OnCheckSlidingExpiration. You'll want to update this in your project's Program.cs file, I personally did it when configuring the application cookie like so:

```
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Events.OnCheckSlidingExpiration = context =>
    {
        var path = context.Request.Path.Value;
        context.ShouldRenew = context.ElapsedTime > (context.Options.ExpireTimeSpan / 2);

        if (path == "/PathWeDontWantToRenewExpiration")
        {
            context.ShouldRenew = false;
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});
```

It's important to include the default functionality for updating the cookie expiry as otherwise the expiry won't update at all, in this code i'm basically saying "It should renew if the elapsed time is over half of the expire time span, unless the call is being made to '/PathWeDontWantToRenewExpiration'".

I also found some examples in the .NET Core GitHub Repo: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/Cookies/samples/CookieSample/Program.cs